# How to populate a ListView from my database using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I was trying to populate my listview with data from sqlite in onclicklistener of my load button.

However, I'm a little confused from the examples I have seen. here is my code in **TotalResults.java**.

```
DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(this);
String name;
int score;
TextView result;
TextView saved;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_total_results);

    result = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textResult);
    saved = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textLoad);
    Button save = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonSave);
    Button load = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonLoad);
    Button delete = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonDelete);
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
      score = intent.getExtras().getInt("score");

      result.setText("Name: "+name+" , Score: "+score );

      save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.addContact(new PlayerData(name,score));
                Log.d("Inserting: ", name);
                Log.d("Inserting: ", Integer.toString(score));

            } 
      });



      load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                List<PlayerData> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                //check to ensure there are users

                setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts));
                if(contacts.size()==0) {
                    String text = "No players stored.";
                    Toast.makeText(TotalResults.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    PlayerData player = contacts.get(0);
                    String showName = player.getName();
                    int showScore = player.getscore();
                    Log.d("Getting:", showName);
                    Log.d("Getting:", Integer.toString(showScore));
                    saved.setText("Player Name: "+showName+" Player Score: "+showScore);
                }
            } 
      });

          delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    List<PlayerData> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                    //check to ensure there are users
                    if(contacts.size()==0) {
                        String text = "No players to delete.";
                        Toast.makeText(TotalResults.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        PlayerData player = contacts.get(0);
                        String showName = player.getName();
                        int showScore = player.getscore();
                        Log.d("Deleting:", showName);
                        Log.d("Deleting:", Integer.toString(showScore));
                        db.deleteContact(player);
                    }

                } 
          });
```

Here is my database code.

```
public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(PlayerData contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getscore()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
PlayerData getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    PlayerData contact = new PlayerData(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2));

    cursor.close();
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<PlayerData> getAllContacts() {
    List<PlayerData> contactList = new ArrayList<PlayerData>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            PlayerData contact = new PlayerData();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setscore(cursor.getInt(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(PlayerData contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getscore());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(PlayerData contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

}

I get an error in this method:

```
  load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    List<PlayerData> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
                    //check to ensure there are users

                    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts));
                    if(contacts.size()==0) {
                        String text = "No players stored.";
                        Toast.makeText(TotalResults.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        PlayerData player = contacts.get(0);
                        String showName = player.getName();
                        int showScore = player.getscore();
                        Log.d("Getting:", showName);
                        Log.d("Getting:", Integer.toString(showScore));
                        saved.setText("Player Name: "+showName+" Player Score: "+showScore);
                    }
                } 
          });
```

and i get an error saying : **cannot instantiate the type ListAdapter, ListAdapter cannot be resolved to a type.**

please help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: post your database code

Comment: Please post what is your doubt or confusion?

Comment: additional info added.

Comment: can you show where you use `setListAdapter`

Comment: use `ActivityName.this` instead of `this`  It would be better to use a custom adapter

Comment: can you show me how to use custom adapter? the error is on 'ListAdapter'. Still kinda new to android. @Raghunandan

Comment: @MiguelRivera check my post. create a Display Activity and use a custom adapter with a custom layout listviewrow inflated for each row. Modify accordingly

Comment: @MiguelRivera it looks like you copied some of the code from somewhere. You have Contacts in some place and PlaterData. So its better you rename them according to your requirements to avoid confusion. I got confused and posted te list of contacts snap shot. let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use a CustomAdapter

```
public class Display extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    DatabaseManager db;
    List<PlayerData> contacts;
    ArrayList<String> con= new ArrayList<String>();
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    CheckBox cb;
    TextView tv1;
    CustomAdapter cus;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        db = new DatabaseManager(this);

           contacts = db.getAllContacts();       
        cus = new CustomAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(cus);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++)

                {
                if(cus.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {
                    sb.append(contacts.get(i).getPhoneNumber());
                    sb.append("\n");

                }                    
            }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sb,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Display.this,SendMessage.class);
                if(con!=null)
                {
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list",con);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int
            position, long id) {
                cus.toggle(position);

            }
    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {
          private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        CustomAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(contacts.size());
             mInflater = (LayoutInflater)Display.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return contacts.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
             vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null); 
             TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
             tv.setText("Name :"+ contacts.get(position).getName());
             tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ contacts.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
             cb.setTag(position);
             cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
             cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            return vi;
        }
         public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);    

        }

    }

}
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

rowlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
        android:text="@string/choice" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each row in listview will look like below. You can click the check box to select and unselect. Later you can get the selected item and do whatever is required.

Click the button at the bottom after checking the checkbox.